# Apache like Rewrite Rules in Openshift

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, jboss7.x, openshift, mod-jk

I have configured Jboss7 on Openshift yesterday. All I need to have an internal rewrite rule to have /members.html -> members.jsp.

This requires user to see members.html while the actual file(members.jsp) is served by Jboss itself.

Dont know correctly how to setup mod_jk if required but surely I would like this thing to work anyways as I have urls submitted in google and shifting site on openshift should not require me to change the URLs.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you have access to the Apache configuration on the server. You would need root permissions for that. Have you considered an alternative approach via a web application filter. There is UrlRewriteFilter - http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/ - which might solve your problem.